# Android TextureView Flicking

Tags: android, drawing

I have tried Romain Guy's TextureView sample code (http://pastebin.com/J4uDgrZ8),  it works great. But when I change lockCanvas(null) into lockCanvas(new Rect(x, y, x+20, y+20)), the example starts to flicker. 
It seems 'lockCanvas(Rect)' can not work well for TextureView or any other reasons?

I am using Motorola XOOM with android 4.0.3. 
Thanks for any help!

the code i modified is as follows:

```
 public void run() {
        float x = 0.0f;
        float y = 0.0f;
        float speedX = 5.0f;
        float speedY = 3.0f;

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(0xff00ff00);

        while (mRunning && !Thread.interrupted()) {
            //final Canvas canvas = mSurface.lockCanvas(null);
            **final Canvas canvas = mSurface.lockCanvas(new Rect((int)x, (int)y,
                                                               (int)(x+20.0f), (int)(y+20.0f)));**  
            try {
                canvas.drawColor(0x00000000, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
                canvas.drawRect(x, y, x + 20.0f, y + 20.0f, paint);
            } finally {
                mSurface.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }

            if (x + 20.0f + speedX >= mSurface.getWidth() || x + speedX <= 0.0f) {
                speedX = -speedX;
            }
            if (y + 20.0f + speedY >= mSurface.getHeight() || y + speedY <= 0.0f) {
                speedY = -speedY;
            }

            x += speedX;
            y += speedY;

            try {
                //Thread.sleep(15);
                  **Thread.sleep(1);**
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // Interrupted
            }
        }
```

I checked it carefully, found that it is "Thread.sleep(1)" together with "lockCanvas(Rect)" leads to the flicker. When use lockCanvas(null), sleep(1) is OK.  So lockCanvas(Rect) can not be refreshed as fast as lockCanvas(null)??

Comment: Could you post your code please? I haven't had an issue with passing a Rect to lockCanvas() in my testing.

Comment: Hi Romain: I have edit my original post. I modified lockCanvas() and duration for Thread.sleep. I found if use Thread.sleep(15), lockCanvas(Rect) seems OK. For lockCanvas(null), Thread.sleep(1) is OK!

Comment: Anyway, I don't think this question is OVER. How can I update quickly via using lockCanvas(Rect) ?? Or there is no such possibility?

Comment: I'm also seeing issues with lockCanvas(rect). The entire view flickers badly, almost like there are two or three different versions of the texture being presented...

Comment: In addition, performance seems to be much worse with lockRect(rect) that is not null. Strange...